# l2 cache connection to cpu in ARM

Tags: architecture, cpu-architecture

I have a question regarding L2 cache and its connection to ARM core.
How is it connected ?  Is it through a cache controller or a direct connection with cache controller also connected to the same bus? I am new to this so sorry if it is obvious.

Comment: You may have better luck asking on http://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I am curious - why do you want to know that? I mean is it for something other than just wanting to know?

Answer (score 0):

At least one architecture says that it is 'through' the cache controller - http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0246h/index.html